# Changing program privileges

Tags: 10.04, video, configuration

I installed a codec under the root user in my Ubuntu 10.04 installation. As you guessed, I can't play a movie using the codec under my normal user account. How do i rectify the problem?

Comment: How did you install the codec ? If it was installed from a package, the user invoking the install is irrelevant.

Comment: I installed using the root terminal <root@sly-laptop> from the command line interface.

Comment: The command was apt-get install w32codecs. I want to enable the codec for all users :)

Comment: As a normal user you should never use the root terminal you must use sudo command. Uninstall w32codecs package and install this: sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras. It will cover majority of codecs you will ever need.

Comment: Can the root user play a movie using the codec?

Comment: Tried but to no avail :)

Comment: @andre -- what did you try last?

Answer (score 2):

From your user account, try `sudo apt-get purge w32codecs` then `sudo apt-get install w32codecs` .

Answer (score -1):

you can try installing again with you currently user use "sudo aptitude -y install non-free-codecs"

Comment: One should never use `-y` unless you really know what you are doing...